# Rails redirect to assoc model after create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `@miniatures` model and a `@lines` model joined via a `@minilines` model.

In the `@miniature show view` I have this link

```
<%= link_to "Add to product line", new_miniline_path(:miniature_id => @miniature) %>
```

To a `New @miniline form` that takes the `:miniature_id` from a hidden field like so

```
<%= f.hidden_field :miniature_id, :value => @miniature.id %>
```

And then you select the desired `@line` from a dropdown.

This all works. What I can't get to work is for the controller to redirect a user back to the originating `@miniature` after the create action works.

This is what I have in my `new` and `create` actions in the controller

```
def new
    @miniline = Miniline.new(@miniature)
    @miniature = Miniature.find(params[:miniature_id])
    @lines = Line.all
  end

  def create
    @miniline = Miniline.new(miniline_params)
    if @miniline.save
      flash[:success] = "Miniature added to product line"
      redirect_to miniature_path(@miniature)
    else
      flash[:success] = "Did not work!!!"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

I've tried various alternatives to `miniature_path(@miniature)` like plain `@miniature` and `miniature_path(:miniature_id)` but to no avail. I suspect my problem is with the passing of the `:miniature_id` to the `@minilines` model. Any help very much appreciated as I've been banging my head for an hour or two.

Comment: What you mean by "not work"? Any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
redirect_to miniature_path(@miniline.miniature)
```

Assuming you have an association setup.

You haven't set @miniature in create which is that that doesn't work

You could also do

```
redirect_to @miniline.miniature
```

Comment: That's it. Great. For some reason I didn't think you could use the association yet because you're making it right there but I guess that's daft cos the save uh, saves it. Thanks tons!